# Changing the server name

Tags: centos, hostname, hosts

I changed the name of the hosts in `/etc/hosts` to

```
IP.GOES.HERE newname
```

Apache does recognize the new server name; but still, via `ssh` i get this on the `ssh` prompt:

```
[root@oldname]
```

Why? Where else do I need to change the server name?

I'm using **CentOS 6.3**

Comment: You need to change the system hostname properly (where "properly" depends entirely on your operating system, which you haven't seen fit to tell us...)

Comment: Sorry for that, just updated the question with that info (CentOS 6.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS you set the system hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.
This setting change takes effect on reboot. To change the hostname on a running system without rebooting use the [`hostname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) command.

Comment: Should clarify that only changing the hostname with the hostname command will set the hostname but will not change the /etc/sysconfig/network configuration. The change wont be persistent over a reboot.

Comment: Also, changing the hostname while the system is running will not affect processes (e.g. Apache) that started with the old name.  It's really a cleaner approach to just change `/etc/sysconfig/network` and reboot, if that's at all an option for you.